# Alternatives to achieve certain output format

Tags: arrays, chemistry

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass[border=10 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,setspace}

\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
{\setstretch{1.5}
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccccccccccccc} 
^{12} \mathrm{C}&+&^{1} \mathrm{H} &\longrightarrow& ^{13}\mathrm{N}&+&\gamma\\
&&&&^{13} \mathrm{N}& \longrightarrow&^{13} \mathrm{C}&+&e^{+}&+&\nu\\
&&&&&&^{13} \mathrm{C}&+&^{\mathrm{l}} \mathrm{H}& \longrightarrow&^{14} \mathrm{N}&+&\gamma\\
&&&&&&&&&&^{14} \mathrm{N}&+&^{\mathrm{l}} \mathrm{H}& \longrightarrow&^{15} \mathrm{O}&+&\gamma\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&^{15} \mathrm{O}& \longrightarrow&^{15} \mathrm{N}&+&e^{+}&+&\nu\\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&^{15} \mathrm{N}&+&^{1} \mathrm{H} &\longrightarrow&^{12} \mathrm{C}&+&^{4} \mathrm{He}
\end{array}}
$ 
\end{document}
```

with the output
[image]
The output is pretty much what I'm looking for, but the way I get it seems rather clunky to me... Is there a better way to get the same output? The only relevant part here is that the same elements in each reaction need to be below each other... The spacing of the other parts doesn't have to be the same as in the picture..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a matter of opinion whether this is less clunky...it eliminates all `&` tab characters, but requires multiple `\stackunder`s and some bracing.

The appearance is a bit different, however "the same elements of each reaction are below each other", as requested by the OP.  While there are no other alignments that apply one may observe that the spacing on any given line is "correct".

```
\documentclass[border=10 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,setspace,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{l}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\setstackgap{L}{1.4\baselineskip}
\stackMath
$\displaystyle
^{12}\mathrm{C}+^{1}\mathrm{H}\longrightarrow             \stackunder{^{13}\mathrm{N}+\gamma}{
 ^{13}\mathrm{N}\longrightarrow                        \stackunder{^{13}\mathrm{C}+e^{+}+\nu}{
  ^{13}\mathrm{C}+^{\mathrm{l}}\mathrm{H}\longrightarrow  \stackunder{^{14}\mathrm{N}+\gamma}{
   ^{14}\mathrm{N}+^{\mathrm{l}}\mathrm{H}\longrightarrow \stackunder{^{15}\mathrm{O}+\gamma}{
    ^{15}\mathrm{O}\longrightarrow                     \stackunder{^{15}\mathrm{N}+e^{+}+\nu}{
     ^{15}\mathrm{N}+^{1}\mathrm{H}\longrightarrow           ^{12}\mathrm{C}+^{4}\mathrm{He}
}}}}}
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Enough simple?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mhchem,parskip}
\def\a{\phantom{\ce{^12C + ^1H ->}}}
\def\b{\phantom{\ce{^13N ->}}}
\begin{document}
\ce{^12C + ^1H -> ^13N + \gamma}\par
\a\ce{^13N -> ^13C + $e^+$ + \nu}\par
\a\b\ce{^13C + ^1H -> ^14N + \gamma}
\end{document}
```

> [image: mwe]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I choose Steven B. Segletes solution since it doesn't require new commands for every reaction, nevertheless a very nice solution.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to align your entries like the way I did (using <kbd>Tab</kbd>) to make it easier to read and modify if needed.
I have used `\newcommand` to create a way for you to enter the data of a row and every cell in the array is encapsulated by `\mathrm{...}`.
Also, I changed the 23 `c`s you had in the array to  `*{23}{c}`.

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[border=10 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools,setspace}
% Usage:
% \data{operand-1}{operator-1}{operand-2}{operator-2}{operand-3}{operator-3}{operand-4}
% Simple example:
% \data{a}{+}{b}{-}{c}{*}{d}
\newcommand{\data}[7]{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \mathrm{#1} & \mathrm{#2} & \mathrm{#3} & \mathrm{#4} & \mathrm{#5} & \mathrm{#6} & \mathrm{#7}
    }%
}%
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
{\setstretch{1.5}
\begin{array}{*{23}{c}} 
                    \data{^{12} C}{+}               {^{1} H}    {\longrightarrow}   {^{13} N}   {+}{\gamma} \\
&&&&                \data{^{13} N}{\longrightarrow} {^{13} C}   {+}                 {e^{+}}     {+}{\nu}    \\
&&&&&&              \data{^{13} C}{+}               {^{1} H}    {\longrightarrow}   {^{14} N}   {+}{\gamma} \\
&&&&&&&&&&          \data{^{14} N}{+}               {^{1} H}    {\longrightarrow}   {^{15} O}   {+}{\gamma} \\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&      \data{^{15} O}{\longrightarrow} {^{15} N}   {+}                 {e^{+}}     {+}{\nu}    \\
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&    \data{^{15} N}{+}               {^{1} H}    {\longrightarrow}   {^{12} C}   {+}{^{4} He}\\
\end{array}}
$
\end{document}
```